# Can't get tiles working with spring mvc 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles

I have a Spring project with which I was able to render a normal view using the InternalResourceViewResolver.  Now I am trying to use tiles to modularize the UI.  When I point the browser to **http://localhost:8080/myapp/tradeaggregation**, I get:

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/tradeaggregation].

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<annotation-driven />

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean name="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/tiles.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ks.kdweb.controllers" />

</beans:beans>
```

tiles.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC 
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" 
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="tradeaggregation" template="/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/tradeAggregation.jsp"/>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

And my controller:

```
@Controller
public class TradeAggregatorController {
    private static final String TITLE = "Trade Aggregation";
    private static final String[] columns = new String[] { "listvalues", "numtrades", "sizesum" };

    @Autowired
    private JdbcAggConfigDefDao aggConfigDefDao;

    @RequestMapping("/tradeaggregation")
    public String load(@RequestParam("configdefid") long configDefId, @RequestParam("aggid") String aggId, Model model) {
        List<AggConfigDef> configs = this.aggConfigDefDao.getAggConfigDefsByType(TradeAggregation.class.getName());
        model.addAttribute("aggConfigs", configs);
        model.addAttribute("title", TITLE);
        model.addAttribute("tradeAggs", this.aggConfigDefDao.getTradeAggregations(configDefId, aggId));
        model.addAttribute("columns", columns);
        return "tradeaggregation";
    }

    public void setAggConfigDefDao(JdbcAggConfigDefDao aggConfigDefDao) {
        this.aggConfigDefDao = aggConfigDefDao;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside you web.xml file try :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: No luck.  I don't even get the PageNotFound exception for no mapping if I change the URL pattern to that.

Comment: try this one <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>, i see this information in the spring mvc documentation


http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html